# $(...).jqBootstrapValidation is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

i am trying to implement a contact us page using bootstrap template. I am a really beginner in asp.net and its my first time using a template.
    I cant really get it where is the problem that is causing the above error. 
I want to when the user click the send Message button to send emails to a current business email. 
    Can anyone help me?

```
contact.cshtml

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
                <h3>Send us a Message</h3>
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Full Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Message:</label>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
                </form>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="~/Scripts/contact_me.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    contact_me.js

    $(function () {

      $('#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
          // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
          // get values from FORM
          var name = $("input#name").val();
          var email = $("input#email").val();
          var phone = $("input#phone").val();
          var message = $("textarea#message").val();
          var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
          // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
          if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
          }
          $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
          $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
            $.ajax({
                     url: "mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              name: name,
              phone: phone,
              email: email,
              message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
              // Success message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
              $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
              // Fail message
              $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
              $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
              }, 1000);
            }
          });
        },
        filter: function() {
          return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
      });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
      });
    });

    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#name').focus(function() {
      $('#success').html('');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my answer morphed through the comments:

> the answer was that the OP added Jquery twice making a conflict in
>   file `jqBootstrapValidation.js`

Also, to help others based on the OP's post, this next part could be helpful as well:

Javascript files need to be loaded in the order of their dependence. Since your custom javascript file, `contact_me.js` depends on functions contained in the javascript file, `jqBootstrapValidation.js`, you need to load `jqBootstrapValidation.js` before `contact_me.js`, to fix this switch the order in which these files are loaded:

```
<script src="~/Content/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script src="~/Scripts/contact_me.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Penelope You may need to clear your browser cache and rebuild your project for the change to take affect. The browser will cache a webpage and script changes will not always take affect without clearing the cache.

Comment: @Penelope What do you mean by, "nothing happened"? Are you still getting the same error??

Comment: yes i have that error
" Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqBootstrapValidation is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM33 contact_me.js:3)
    at e (VM30 jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (VM30 jquery.min.js:2) "

Comment: @Penelope Check your `web.config` to make sure unobtrusive validation is turned off, or it can cause JQuery to be added twice to your project which can cause a conflict according to this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087885/jqbootstrapvalidation-is-not-a-function)

Comment: so i replace the line "<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
" with " <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>"
in my web.config, but still got the same error

Comment: @Penelope Have you opened your browsers developer tools and checked to make sure that the file `jqBootstrapValidation.js` is loading correctly when you start up the project?

Comment: @Penelope Are you using Visual Studio as your IDE?

Comment: @Penelope Have you tried deleting everything from the obj and bin folders and rebuilding? Or try switching to a different browser for running it through local IIS? Also, look at my updated answer, it looks like from another post on here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181690/jqbootstrap-validation-form-error) and the accepted answer that the jqBootstraValidation.js needs loaded before Jquery

Comment: @Penelope Please see my updated answer for the order of the script files.

Comment: okay found the problem..i was trying to import twice jquery,solved thank you

Comment: @Penelope If my answer and comments helped, you may mark my answer as the accepted one , thank you.

Comment: sure sorry for forgetting